# Jetta 2001 GLS 2.0, AC clutch won't come on

Tags: ac, jetta

I have a problem, 2001 Jetta 2.0 GLS, installed entire new system, compressor, clutch, dryer, expansion valve, worked great for about 4 months then nothing. Clutch won't come on. Acted like it was the climate control panel, took dash out, ordered new panel from APW, installed panel, still nothing. I thought it could have been the manual A/C switch,. However, when I pulled the glove box & radio out, now when I push in on the MAX or recirculate switch the parking brake light comes on on the dash & buzzer sounds!!! Go Figure???

Comment: Did you check your pressures? If so, what are they? If you don't have enough refrigerant pressure, the clutch won't turn on (unless you go to extreme measures).